# Checking if an attribute exists within an array of loaded attributes

Tags: attributes, magento-1, advanced-search, array

I have an array of makes and values printed as following:

```
$name='makemagento';
$attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem();
$attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 
print_r($attributeOptions);

array($attributeOptions);
```

This gives me a list of results like this:

```
Array
(
[0] =&gt; Array
    (
        [value] =&gt; 1035
        [label] =&gt; Alfa Romeo
    )


)
```

I am trying to check if a value exists.

I do the following:

```
if (in_array('Alfa Romeo', $attributeOptions['label']))
 {
 echo "Match found";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Match not found";
 }
```

But i can't seem to successfully get a "match found" result from this.

Can anybody advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this -

```
foreach ($attributeOptions as $option) {
   if ($option['label'] == 'Alfa Romeo') {
      echo "Match found";
   }
   else
   {
     echo "Match Not found";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`in_array()` does not work on multidimensional arrays. You could write a recursive function to do that for you:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
echo in_array_r("Alfa Romeo", $attributeOptions) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: This is probably correct, but a bit to advanced for my basic php knowledge. I apreciate the help!